# MariaDB service does not start after deleting huge amount of data

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb

I've executed a query which deleted about 18 million records. After executing this query, mysql stopped responding to queries.
I've restarted the server and now I can't start mysql service using the following command:

```
service mysql start
```

Maybe it just prints error but I can't find the error-log file. I am running CentOS 6 and have installed mariaDB from it's official repository using yum.

What should I do in order to start mysql? I don't care if the query just gets canceled. I can see that some mysqld process are eating CPU and I/O. I think maybe it's still trying to execute this query.

Comment: How did you stop the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that "I can't start mysql service ...", but you can see some mysqld process. Try execute:

```
service mysql status
```

If service is started, then try to stop it and run mariaDB in safe mode with error-logging enabled. If service is not started, then try to kill mysqld process (be aware of responsibility) and run mariaDB in safe mode.

For more details about safe mode see official [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqld_safe/).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who views this, you can also use the mysqladmin command to list all running queries and selectively kill them if need be. This would preserve any other queries that were executing on that instance.

```
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqladmin.html
```

Note that SHOW VARIABLES will return the location of MySQL's logs, if that is also needed.